# save as "proper" csv / delete quotes from CSV except for where comma exists

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I am downloading a CSV from a SharePoint site. It comes with a `.csv` file extension.

When I inspect the file's contents by opening it in Notepad, I see data that looks like this sample row:

`"TITLE",OFFICE CODE,="","CUSTOMER'S NAME",ACCOUNT`

I want the data look like this:

`TITLE,OFFICE CODE,,"CUSTOMER'S NAME",ACCOUNT`

One way to solve this problem is manually. When I open the file in Excel and save it (without altering anything), it prompts me with the following: `fileOrig.csv may contain features that are not compatible with CSV (Comma delimited). Do you want to keep the workbook in this format?` When I save it, and then inspect it in Notepad, the data is formatted according to how I want it do look.

Is there a quick way to resave the original CSV **with PowerShell**?

If there is no quick way to resave the file **with PowerShell**, I would like to use PowerShell to parse it.

These are the parsing rules I want to introduce:

- Remove encapsulating doublequote from cells that do not contain a `,` char
- Remove the `=` char

I tried writing a test script that just looks at the column that potentially contains `,` chars. It is supposed to find the cells that do not contain a `,` char, and remove the doublequotes that encapsulate the text. It does not work, because I think it tosses the doublequote upon `Import-Csv`

```
$source = 'I:\dir\fileOrig.csv'
$dest = 'I:\dir\fileStaging.csv'
$dest2 = 'I:\dir\fileFinal.csv'

get-content $source |
    select -Skip 1 |
    set-content "$file-temp"
move "$file-temp" $dest -Force

$testcsv = Import-Csv $dest

foreach($test in $testcsv)
{
        #Write-Host $test."CUSTOMER NAME"  

        if($test."CUSTOMER NAME" -NotLike "*,*") {
            $test."CUSTOMER NAME" -replace '"', ''
        }
}  

$testcsv | Export-Csv -path $dest2 -Force
```

Can someone please help me either with implementing the logic above, or if you know of a better way to save the file as a proper CSV, can you please let me know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Excel can handle the problem, why not use a vbs script to automate it?  Use notepad to create "Fix.vbs" with the following lines:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\test\test.csv") 
objworkbook.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
objworkbook.Save
objexcel.quit
```

run it from a command prompt and it should do the trick.

Comment: works like a charm. i pasted into Access VBA code. than you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I see that there's already an approved answer, I'm just offering an alternative.

If you want to keep it in PowerShell you could do this:

```
$File = 'I:\dir\fileOrig.csv'
$dest = 'I:\dir\fileStaging.csv'
$Output = 'I:\dir\fileFinal.csv'
$CSV = Import-Csv $file
$Members = $test|gm -MemberType Properties|select -ExpandProperty name
$test|%{$row=$_;$Members|%{if(!($row.$_ -match "\w+")){$row.$_=$null}};$_=$row}|export-csv $dest -NoTypeInformation -Force
gc $file|%{($_.split(",") -replace "^`"(.*)`"$","`$1") -join ","}|Out-File $Output
```

That imports the CSV, makes sure that there are words (letters, numbers, and/or underscores... don't ask my why underscores are considered words, RegEx demands that it be so!) in each property for each entry, exports the CSV, then runs through the file again as just text splitting at commas and if it shows up enclosed in double quotes it strips those, re-joins the line, and then outputs it to a file. The only thing that I don't think shows up like your "preferred output" in the OP is that instead of `"CUSTOMER'S NAME"` you get `CUSTOMER'S NAME`.

Comment: +1 Thank you for this. I will test both and will decide whether to implement it this way.